# strtotime returning false date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a problem with strtotime function in php, i'm trying to convert mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd. The date is entered on the text box and on submit it should save the date to the database. the problem is it returns a wrong date(1970-01-01) each time,which means my code isn't taking the variable i use to store the date, My code is:

```
//dateconvert
$submitdate = date($_POST['date']);
$date   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($submitdate));

//storeindb
$query ="INSERT INTO ticket SET date = '$date'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I'm a newbie,please help.

Comment: `mm-dd-yyyy` is not a format `strtotime` can translate, it should be either `mm/dd/yyyy` (interpreted as american date) or `dd-mm-yyyy` (interpreted as european, or at least italian, date)

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['date']?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari i've used mm/dd/yyyy but it still returns the same value

Comment: What what is the actual posted value?

Comment: @AcyclicTau it takes the date entered in textbox(value:2013-10-25)

Comment: @MatteoTassinari It works now just removed the date function..thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

You need to use the forward slash separator for mm/dd/yyyy formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code as:

```
$submitdate = $_POST['date'];
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($submitdate));
```

Hope this hepls.

Answer (score 1):

date format in `$submitdate` is incorrect Because the format yyyy/mm/dd should be yyyy-mm-dd so you will need to replace your `/` characters.

Try this:

```
$submitdate = str_replace("/","-",$_POST['date']);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($submitdate));
```

Comment: This i've used earlier... doesnot work...returns the same value as before

Comment: then i guess your date must is in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.If so change it to `yyyy-mm-dd` format.