# convert date from string to mysql datetime field

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a string **31/05/2017**

And I want to convert it to MYSQL format, `2017-05-31 00:00:00`.
What I have done is.

```
$dateString = '31/05/2017';
$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

But `strtotime` is returning `false`.

Comment: possible solution and similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Comment: @Abdul Ghaffar is it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

```
<?php
$dateString = str_replace("/", "-", '31/05/2017');
$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);
var_dump(strtotime($dateString));
echo $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
?>
```

check below links

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

[strtotime returning false date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587113/strtotime-returning-false-date)

Answer (score 0):

Please try Following,

```
$dateString = '31/05/2017';
$timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $dateString )); 
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Thanks.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.